# Endless Loop in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, jdoodle

My assignment is to ask the user for input and the output would return their name.

Here is my code :

```
section .data
user:     db  'Hello.What is your name ?   '
user_L:    equ $-user ;length of the UserNameMsg segment
hello:     db '  Hello'
hello_L:   equ $-hello

section .bss 
   user_v:  resb 23
section  .text
   global _start    

_start: 
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx, user
 mov edx, user_L
   int 0x80

     mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0
   mov ecx, user
   mov edx, 23
   int 0x80
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, hello
   mov edx, hello_L
   int 0x80
   mov eax,4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, user_v
   mov edx, 23
   int 0x80
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 0x80
```

When i ran my code in [JDoodle's online assembler](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/u9k) I get the error saying:

> Timeout -  Some common reasons for Timeout Your Program may have a endless loop

I'm not sure what to do to fix this error.

Comment: it's very difficult to develop assembly code without proper debugger. Consider setting up some full machine with proper tools, like maybe install some 32 bit linux into some virtual machine, and install there the gcc + binutils and edb-debugger, and maybe some gdb front-end, etc... may take a time to find everything you need and make it work, but just running the executable will not tell you much about what is happening inside.

Comment: BTW your code looks almost correct on first sight, I think before input you did want `mov ecx, user_v` instead of `mov ecx,user`, and I didn't check the `int 0x80` services docs if you are putting correct arguments for them, but otherwise there's nothing plain wrong about it. May you also provide build command, how you produce the final executable? And which online assembler you use? Also any particular reason why you are learning 32 bit x86 with online assembler? Are you free to choose other platform, etc?

Comment: Not seeing a loop. Is it possible the online tool you're using just doesn't handle interrupts? Try just assembling it on your machine and running it locally.